# Winefile copy and paste option. Can't find paste

Tags: wine

Nothing more to say. I right click a file and I see "copy" and "cut" then I go to the destination folder, right click, ... where's paste??!!! I searched the menus on top. Nothing. I tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install wine again from the terminal, and type:

```
 Sudo apt-get install wine1.4
 Sudo apt-get update
 Sudo apt-get install wine1.4 wine tricks
 Sudo apt-get install wine
```

and that should work fine.